# Add subgroup labels to a jitter plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I have a nearly-boxplot like jitter-plot:

```
dt <- rbind(se,cb,cb.se)
qplot(ds, size, data=dt, geom="jitter", colour=root, facets = test ~ .)
```

[image: plot]

I'd love to put a summary label for each group in the middle of the plot - for example the size totals here:

```
 aggregate(list(size=dt$size), list(dt$ds, dt$test), sum)

   Group.1  Group.2   size
1     b217       se   9847
2      c10       se  97296
3     c613       se  21633
4       c7       se 207540
...
```

I've tried using `+ geom_text(aes(x=ds, y=128, label=sum(size)), size=2)` to add labels, but I get the same label on each position - how can I get the sum of just that section of data?

**Edit:**
Here's where I'm at now - maybe I'm just going in the wrong direction

```
data <- rbind(se,cb,cb.se)
labels <-ddply(data, c("ds", "test"), function(df) sum(df$size))
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=ds)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(y=size, colour=root)) +
  geom_text(data=labels, aes(x=ds, y=600, label=V1), size=3) +
  facet_wrap(test ~ .)
```

This code doesn't work - I get an `undefined columns selected` error... somewhere.  Maybe it's because of the multiple `data=` sections?

Comment: From a quick read, that code looks fine to me.  It's hard to say more without a reproducible example.

Comment: I have posted a solution. Unfortunately, since you haven't provided sample data, I had to recreate random data.  This means the solution may or may not reflect your own data.  For future reference, you will attract more answers if you make a minimal example of your problem and paste some sample data that we can all use to reproduce your problem.  Anyway, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you don't provide sample data, I shall demonstrate a solution using random data.

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 100
dat <- data.frame(
    ds = sample(paste("x", 1:8, sep=""), n, replace=TRUE),
    size = runif(n, 0, 250),
    root = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), n, replace=TRUE),
    test = sample(c("se", "cb", "cb.se"), n, replace=TRUE) 
)


head(dat)
  ds      size  root  test
1 x3 163.68098  TRUE cb.se
2 x3  88.29932  TRUE    se
3 x5  67.56504 FALSE    cb
4 x8 248.17102  TRUE    cb
5 x2 158.37332  TRUE    cb
6 x8  53.30203 FALSE cb.se

p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=ds, y=size)) + 
  geom_jitter(aes(colour=root)) + 
  facet_grid(test~.)
```

Create the data frame containing label data.  Note the use of `summarize`.  This tells `ddply` to create a new column to the data.frame

```
labels <- ddply(dat, .(ds, test), summarize, size=round(sum(size), 0))
head(labels)
  ds  test size
1 x1    cb  193
2 x1 cb.se  615
3 x1    se  274
4 x2    cb  272
5 x2 cb.se  341
6 x2    se 1012

p + geom_text(aes(x=ds, label=size, y=128), data=labels, size=2)
```

[image]

Comment: This looks exactly like what I needed.  Thanks!

Comment: @Thelema, glad I could be of help.  (Remember to allocate the bounty, since this doesn't happen automatically)

Comment: well deserved. nice. and quick :)

Comment: Got it.  Luckily SO reminds me too.  Now I know how to do this right.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here. It may be helpful
[Adding direct labels to ggplot2 and lattice plots](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2010/01/03/directlabels-adding-direct-labels-to-ggplot2-and-lattice-plots/)

Comment: directlabels doesn't solve my problem, it doesn't position well on jitter plots, and it wants to use my legend labels to label the chart instead of provided labels.